# Why is it telling me that I can't suggest an edit on Meta when I have over 4k rep?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing, meta

[image: eeeerwhat]

In the above screenshot, It's telling me that I can't suggest an edit on meta - *but I have had over 2k for ~8 months*.

So why can't I edit [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9706/how-do-i-earn-the-50-points-to-be-able-to-comment)? Is it because it was merged?

Comment: @randal'thor Since you *do* have the superpowers, can you please remove [star-trek] from that question?

Comment: As you wish </westley>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It’s because it’s (basically) locked

You can’t edit the post because it has been merged, yes. Thus the remaining stub post [has been locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post).

As detailed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256185/wrong-explanation-about-why-cant-i-edit-locked-post), hovering over a locked post on meta will produce precisely that error. Similarly [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302383/reason-for-not-letting-me-edit-a-meta-post).  As mentioned in the comments on the first post, it seems that the system interprets any edit made under less-than-unlimited privileges—including not having the privileges at all—as a suggested edit, for the purposes of throwing errors.

I can reproduce that error by hovering over the edit button, although I’m not sure why your box is a different color.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's a Linux thing?

Comment: @Mithrandir - It is definitely a matter of style.